# How can I maximize my main window and prevent resize in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to maximize my main qt window upon running and prevent the user from resizing it. I have tried

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow widget;
    widget.showMaximized();
    widget.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Which does maximize the window, along with

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

which does grey out the "restore down", "maximize" button located in the title bar in the middle of minimize and close window.

But I am still able to drag the title bar down to unsnap the maximized window and then readjust the size with the corner and edges.

How can I prevent the ability to unsnap the window and no strictly no resizing.

Thanks!

Comment: Get the geometry of the display and set the fixed size of the QMainWindow to the corresponding values. Adjust if needed (task bar?). For further information see the documentation of QWidget. It is inherited from there.

Answer (score 5):

If you want Window frame disappear and maximize-lose-restoredown buttons invisible, you can modify UI part of your code as:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
   ui->setupUi(this);
   this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint); //Makes the frame invisible
   this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized); //Maximizes the window
}
```